# Library to support H.264 AVC .mp4 on Android 2.2, 2.3?

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, mp4, http-live-streaming

I am working on a video application and we are generating videos in **H.264 AVC** Codec. As per [Android Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core) this codec is supported in Android 3.0+ versions.

I wonder if there is any free library that help us to play this format on 2.2 or 2.3. I found [a library](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle) but it is not free.

I want to support HTTP live streaming for our application and the issue is same.

Comment: what is your "targetSdkVersion"? If its below 11(3.0) changing it to 11 or above might help

Comment: Target version is 18 and still face the issue on lower devices.

Comment: can u share the video properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used ServeStream in my project you can find the description from http://sourceforge.net/projects/servestream/files/

And you can also check [faplayer-android](https://github.com/shaobin0604/faplayer).

Comment: FYI (I developed ServeStream) I created a stand alone library based on the FFmpeg-based media player used in ServeStream: https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer

Answer (score 1):

[Servestream](http://servestream.sourceforge.net/) is another opensource ffmpeg based media player.

It plays mms streams such as mms://streaming.radionz.co.nz/national-mbr.

It has a FFMpegMediaPlayer class that looks just like a regular MediaPlayer.

It plays videos too.

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely no such library. If you're willing to accept software decoding, you can probably build something around ffmpeg/libav and NDK.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you these porting Libraries 。
ffmpeg ,vlc ,gstreamer

faplayer-android  open source url :[faplayer-android](https://github.com/shaobin0604/faplayer)